# Поменять местами выражения, используя регулярные выражения

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, shell

Есть несколько строк, которые имеют вид.

```
"Ua": ["U<sub>A</sub>","desc"],  
"Ub": ["U<sub>B</sub>","desc"],  
"Uc": ["U<sub>C</sub>","desc"],
```

Нужно поменять местами выражения чтобы результат стал вида:

```
"U<sub>A</sub>": ["Ua","desc"],  
"U<sub>B</sub>": ["Ub","desc"],  
"U<sub>C</sub>": ["Uc","desc"],
```

Пытался использовать регулярные выражения sed, но к рабочему варианту не пришел.
Как можно сделать?

Comment: скрипт на `python` использовать можно?

Comment: хотелось бы но нет. решение нужно на shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

симметричное преобразование (применив дважды, можно получить исходные строки):

```
$ sed -r 's/("U[^"]+)(.*)("U[^"]+)/\3\2\1/' file
```

где `file`, как я понял, должен содержать:

```
"Ua": ["U<sub>A</sub>","desc"],  
"Ub": ["U<sub>B</sub>","desc"],  
"Uc": ["U<sub>C</sub>","desc"],
```

---

**после уточнений** о том, что в начале строки могут встретиться пробельные символы, буква («U» в вопросе) может быть и другой, и вообще нужно поменять местами первую строку в кавычках со второй, привожу второй вариант:

```
$ sed -r 's/^\s*("[^"]+")([^"]*)("[^"]+")/\3\2\1/' file
```

из файла:

```
"Ra": ["R<sub>A</sub>","desc"],
 "Ub": ["U<sub>B</sub>","desc"],
"Ic": ["I<sub>C</sub>","desc"],
```

получаем:

```
"R<sub>A</sub>": ["Ra","desc"],
"U<sub>B</sub>": ["Ub","desc"],
"I<sub>C</sub>": ["Ic","desc"],
```

Comment: Большая статья по sed. Много примеров. Возможно будет полезна не только мне. http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/consol/HuMan/sed-ru.html

Answer (score 1):

Можешь испольовать следующее регулярное выражение: `"U(?<g1>[^"]*)": \["U(?<g2>[^"]*)"(?<g3>.*)` с заменой на `"U${g2}": ["${g1}${g3}`

Пример реализации на C#:

```
string inputData = @"""Ua"": [""UA"",""desc""],
""Ub"": [""UB"",""desc""],
""Uc"": [""UC"",""desc""],";

string pattern = @"""U(?<g1>[^""]*)"": \[""U(?<g2>[^""]*)""(?<g3>.*)";
RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, regexOptions);
string replacement = @"""U${g2}"": [""${g1}${g3}";
string result = regex.Replace(inputData, replacement);
```